# Select with join into custom type

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have entities that look like the following:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Relation.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Relation> relatedList;
}

@Entity
@Data
public class Relation {
    @Id
    private UUID id;
}
```

In addition, I have another type:

```java
@Data
public class OtherType extends MyEntity {
    private String otherField;

    public OtherType(UUID id, List<Relation> relations, String otherField) {
        super(id, relations);
        this.otherField = otherField;
    }
}
```

What I want to do now is to select the objects in the table of `MyEntity` together with some additional info (`otherField`) into an object of type `OtherType`:

```sql
select e.id, e.relatedList, 'otherStuff' as otherField from MyEntity e
```

If I use this query with HQL, it converts `e.relatedList` to `. as col_x_x_`, which obviously is a syntax error. I was trying to use a native query, but that just says that OtherType is not an Entity. If I use a NamedNativeQuery with a resultSetMapping, it can't map a list of values to a Collection (`No dialect mapping for JDBC type 1111`). What I also tried is use the postgres `array_agg` function to get only an array of IDs for my relation, but that can't be mapped either. Is there any way to achieve this except defining a constructor in `OtherType` that accepts a single value instead of a list, doing an actual real SQL join (where every instance of `Relation` adds another `MyEntity` row), and mapping that afterwards?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to return a list of object which is not entity from a typed query in hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58190838/how-to-return-a-list-of-object-which-is-not-entity-from-a-typed-query-in-hiberna)

Comment: @mentallurg I don't think so, since my problem lies entirely in the relation (retrieving multiple related objects per row)

Comment: 1) If you need a *flat* object, then this is exactly a solution. It does not matter how you define a query. Important is that for every selected row you can create an object, and this object doesn't need to be an entity. Some of its attributes will be the same as in *MyEntity*, some can be as in *OtherType*, some can be as in *Relation*. 2) If you need actually 2 types - some non-entity with relation to another non-entity, this will word, you will have to define both of them as entities.

Comment: @mentallurg I need the second possibility you mentioned; however, as far as I'm aware, Entity = database table, which I definitely do not want...

Comment: 1) "Entity = database table" - no, this is no necessary. An entity can be spread across mutiple tables. A simple example is strategy *Table per subclass* when you map hierarchy of classes. So mapping a "flat" entity would be not a problem. 2) For every table you can define more than one entity. E.g. in one case you need the whole table with 50 attribute, in other you need only 3 attributes from the same table. Then you just define 2 entities with different names for the same table. But don't use both in the same transactions :)

Comment: You can define such "light weight" entities and even relations between them.

Comment: @mentallurg that sounds good, but after some research the only way I have found to have a non-table entity is `@Subselect`, where I again loose HQL and therefore mapping of my related objects, or am I missing something here?

Comment: TO use HQL you need entities. Why don't you define 2 entity types for your tables? One entity with all attributes and one with fewer that you need in this particular case. It is up to you to use or not to use it. But this is a normal approach that works well, it uses the same standard than other entities. There are no any tricks. Everything is documented and works predictable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model. Since the attribute name is used as default mapping, you mostly don't need explicit mappings as 80% of the use cases is to have DTOs that are a subset of the entity model.

The interesting part for you is, that it supports collections. A sample model could look like the following:

```
@EntityView(MyEntity.class)
public interface MyEntityView {
    @IdMapping
    UUID getId();
    String getOtherField();
    List<RelationView> getRelations();
}
@EntityView(Relation.class)
public interface RelationView {
    @IdMapping
    UUID getId();
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`MyEntityView p = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, MyEntityView.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features